# Cast column TO_DATE with two and four digit years

Tags: postgresql

I have a table *multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans* where employees enter the date in two and four digit year format. When I try to convert this using TO_DATE I get an error in my WHERE statement:

> ERROR:  invalid value "/1" for "DD"
> DETAIL:  Value must be an integer.

How can I get my query to work when employees aren't using four digit years? They may enter 01232023 or 01/23/23. I'm assuming I have to write a function. Being new to Postgresql this isn't something I haven't done before. Any help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN
multi_app_documentation.nsma1_code = 'DATE' 
THEN TO_DATE(multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans, 'MMDDYYYY') END AS "Procedure Date", 

    ' ' AS "Case Confirmation Number",
    ip_visit_1.ipv1_firstname AS "Patient First", 
    ip_visit_1.ipv1_lastname AS "Patient Last", 
    visit.visit_sex AS "Patient Gender", 
    TO_CHAR(visit.visit_date_of_birth, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "DOB", 
    visit.visit_id AS "Account Number", 
    visit.visit_mr_num AS "MRN",
    ' ' AS "Module",
    ' ' AS "Signed off DT", 
    CASE WHEN
    multi_app_documentation.nsma1_code = 'CRNA' THEN multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans END AS "Primary CRNA",
    ' ' AS "Secondary CRNA",
    ' ' AS "Primary Anesthesiologist",
' ' AS "Secondary Anesthesiologist",
' ' AS "Canceled Yes/No" 
FROM
    multi_app_documentation
    INNER JOIN ip_visit_1 ON multi_app_documentation.nsma1_patnum = ip_visit_1.ipv1_num
    INNER JOIN visit ON ip_visit_1.ipv1_num = visit.visit_id 
WHERE
multi_app_documentation.nsma1_code = 'DATE' AND TO_DATE(multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans, 'MMDDYYYY') = CURRENT_DATE 

ORDER BY
ip_visit_1.ipv1_lastname;
```

**Update**:

Dates entered into multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans (which is a varchar field I cannot change) are put in as 01232023 or 01/23/23 or 1/23/2023. I need these to be converted to MMDDYYYY always. Also, in my where statement I need to convert it TO_DATE and pull CURRENT_DATE. This is problematic because the dates stored in there can be 01232023 or 1/23/2023 or 01/23/2023. Please advise.

Comment: Update: Dates entered into multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans (which is a varchar field I cannot change) are put in as 01232023 or 01/23/23 or 1/23/2023. I need these to be converted to MMDDYYYY always. Also, in my where statement I need to convert it TO_DATE and pull CURRENT_DATE. This is problematic because the dates stored in there can be 01232023 or 1/23/2023 or 01/23/2023. Please advise.

Comment: `01232023 or 01/23/23 or 1/23/2023` no the same as `01232023 or 1/23/2023 or 01/23/2023`. You need to add to your question a validated list of the string formats the dates can appear as.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN strpos('01232023', '/') > 0 THEN
        to_date('01/23/23', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    ELSE
        to_date('01232023', 'MMDDYYYY')
    END AS dt;

01/23/2023

SELECT
    CASE WHEN strpos('01/23/23', '/') > 0 THEN
        to_date('01/23/23', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    ELSE
        to_date('01232023', 'MMDDYYYY')
    END AS dt;

01/23/2023
```

Though you would be better off storing these values in a `date` using the above to convert to a `date`.

**UPDATE**

Nest the `CASE`'s.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN 'DATE' = 'DATE' THEN
        CASE WHEN strpos('01/23/23', '/') > 0 THEN
            to_date('01/23/23', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        ELSE
            to_date('01232023', 'MMDDYYYY')
        END
    END AS dt;

dt     
------------
 01/23/0023
```

In your case in `'DATE' = 'DATE'` replace the first `'DATE'` with `multi_app_documentation.nsma1_code`.

Comment: I am unable to have them store in a date field. Our software vendor just makes it a string field where I'm pulling the info from. Also, the date changes as well from day to day. It won't always be 01/23/2023.

Comment: Substitute `multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans`  or whatever the field is for the date string in the examples above.

Comment: How would I do so when I have to indicate that multi_app_documentation.nsma1_code 'DATE' first?

Comment: See **UPDATE** for solution.

Comment: What if I wanted anything entered in MM/DD/YY format to be formatted into MMDDYYYY?

Comment: 1) `to_date()` converts a string to a `date` and said `date` does not have a format. 2) Update your question with more detail on what you are trying to achieve? Example input data and expected output would be useful.

Comment: I have added an update. Thanks for your assistance in this. I've been working on it for two weeks and am stuck.

Comment: Add update to question body not as comment.